extend type of all html elements in react
I'm writing a library that has a detection for a custom data- attribute. I want to have auto-complete enabled for it on HTML elements.
Tried extending HTMLElement, a Method that is used to calculate JSX types but failed to do. it seems like the only way to do so is extending each individual elements in IntrinsicElements, but I want to do it more dynamically. Tried using an override outside with a mapped type to intrinsicElements then having it extend the override, but it ends in a recursive call.
is there a way to achieve it without having to extend each HTML element?

Could you clarify your question? Your question is quite abstract. How dynamically is "more dynamically"? Could you show some example code snippet?

i just want to add auto-complete for data-my-custom-atrribute on all html elements like div, a, img etc. so when the user in visual studio code for example types in data-m, they can see the full name and type

You shouldn't need to add this to your types as its already supported by html elements. Its a common use case for a lot of libraries.
See the docs here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes

how can i add typescript to it globally though? because I want to add support for native HTML elements not wrapper stuff that I can pass as props

what exactly are you trying to achieve with this?

i just want to add auto-complete for data-my-custom-atrribute on all html elements like div, a, img etc. so when the user in visual studio code for example types in data-m, they can see the full name and type
